# Set background-image for ui-paginator

Tags: css, primefaces

is it possible set a specified color for ui-paginator element?

In my CSS application I have:

```
.ui-icon {
background-image: url("img/ui-icons_ffffff.png") !important;}
```

and it works.

I try to add:

```
.ui-paginator-next {
background-image: url("../img/ui-icons_000000.png") !important;
}

.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-next .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-prev .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-first .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-last .ui-icon {
background-image: url("../img/ui-icons_000000.png") !important;
}
```

because I would like paginator arrow with black color. It doesn't work.

Comment: The first image seems to be in different folder (img) while the second code snippet refers a different one (../images), is that correct? It would help if you also posted folder structure of your resources folder (the relevant paths, no need to post full project structure).

Comment: My wrong. I edit path now that it's correct. It would seem that with .ui-icon is not possible to use another ui.icon in other component

Comment: Are you sure "../" needs to be there? Can't you just have the same as for `.ui-icon`, i.e. starting with "img/"?

Comment: What is the relation with actual pagination? Just a plain html css issue, right?

Comment: @Sva.Mu: I'm sure, if I change in .ui-icon the background-image, I see the change.

Comment: @Kukeltje: Just a plain html css issue. I believe that isn't possible to use another ui-icon if there is one configured...

Comment: Next time, also post the generated html from a minimimal example. Everybody with css knowledge can help then.

Comment: So, is there not solution?

Answer (score 0):

Provided your path to the images is correct, you can use something like this - tested in IE 10, Firefox and Chrome.

```
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-next .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-prev .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-first .ui-icon,
.ui-paginator .ui-paginator-last .ui-icon {
    background: url("../img/ui-icons_000000.png") no-repeat left top !important;
}
```

Just keep your `.ui-icon` unchanged and remove the definition for `.ui-paginator-next` your second code snippet begins with.

Comment: Thank you for response. There is something strange. ui-icons_000000.png file is in my folder but if I can to get this file by browser: http://localhost:8080/myapp/img/ui-icons_000000.png I don't see nothing. Then I don't get any error but only a white page. My folder img contains both ui-icons_000000.png and ui-icons_ffffff.png. Moreover, with your setting, I see both paginator with white icon.

Comment: Also, I just found out that it works if I set css for paginator with this image: ui-icons_333333.png that there isn't in my folder.... Perhaps images can be registered?

Comment: Please update the question with your recent findings so that others can see it as well. To be honest, I'm not sure if I understand your point now...

Comment: Solved. That file is in my theme .jar. Thanks.